# Which IP address should I put on 'Server IP Whitelist' facebook developer console? (400 error from Facebook)

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

I'm building oauth2 facebook authorization and the errors prints "This IP address is not on the Server IP whitelist"

Is the 'IP address' referring to my public ip address or my localhost?

I put both but I'm getting still same error.

From Facebook Developer Console > Advanced,

```
Server IP Whitelist:          10.0.2.2, 223.108.215.xxx    <- replaced numbers with x
Update Settings IP Whitelist: 223.108.215.xxx
```

Which IP address should I put? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Facebook API you can put localhost also (http://localhost:8000) in `SITE_URL`. It worked for me when I tried. Unlike Twitter or Google API where it works only with production server.

And you **don't need to add server IP whitelist** to make app working.

Comment: @Astick Anand I tried to put localhost, http://localhost, localhost:8000, http://localhost:8000. But it says Invalid IP address format. :(

Comment: You are creating facebook app right?? using `developers.facebook.com`

Comment: Yes. Advanced > Security > Server IP Whitelist. I could put 127.0.0.1 (localhost) but it still says "This IP address is not on the Server IP whitelist"

Comment: Hold on I am looking again into that.

Comment: While creating a facebook api, just enter the display name, app domain and site url in **basic settings**. You dont need to give server ip white list in **advanced settings**. You just provide `site url` : `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: Um actually I already have `http://localhost:8000/`. My question was how to set **server IP whitelist**. Um... am I misunderstanding??

Comment: I think you don't need to. So you can skip that part of adding server ip whitelist if it's not working and still the app will work fine. I am using the same way.

Comment: HOLLY CRAB I just deleted all whitelist and it works like a magic. THANK you so much omg I've been stock on this problem for days thank you so much